# Proving the limit is 0

Tags: limits, derivatives, taylor-expansion

$f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ if $f(x)\neq0$

Prove that for every $m>0,f(x) / x^m →0$ as x → 0.

How should I prove this? I tried to use L'Hospital's Rule, but for $e^{-1/x^2}$, it'll become quite complicated to write its derivatives after m times. I tried to use taylor expansion of $e^x$ as well. But I'm stuck again on how to calculate this limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not hard to prove by induction that $f$ is a $C^\infty$ function and each $f^{(n)}$ can be written as $P_n\left(\frac1x\right)e^{-1/x^2}$ for some polynomial function $P_n(x)$; furthermore, $f^{(n)}(0)=0$.

So, the Taylor polynomial $Q_m(x)$ of order $m$ of $f$ at $0$ is the null polynomial and, since$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-Q_m(x)}{x^m}=0$$(this is a general property of the Taylor polynomials), we have $\lim_{\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^m}=0$.

You can also do it using that fact that$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^m}=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\left(\frac1x\right)^m}=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{x^m}{e^{x^2}}$$and it is easy to see that this limit is $0$.

Comment: Actually what you used to prove this is the following questions I need to solve. Proving  this limit is 0 is the first part, and then I need to use this part to prove what you said about polynomial functions here. So I'm wondering the direct proof of this limits. @José Carlos Santos

Comment: I have added a new paragraph no my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was think of. I tried to use L'Hospital's Rule, but for the denominator, after m times derivatives, it would go quite complicated. Do I need to show it exactly for a formal proof?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Showing *what* in a formal proof?

Comment: Showing $e^{x^2}$'s derivatives after using L'Hospital's Rule for m times.

Comment: It is easy to prove that the $n$th derivative of $e^{x^2}$ is of the form $P_n(x)e^{x^2}$ for some polynomial $P_n(x)$; therefore, $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\left(e^{x^2}\right)^{(m)}=\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $m \in \mathbb{R}^+$, now we study the limit of $\dfrac{f(x)}{x^m}$ for $x \in \mathcal{U}(0)$.
$$\dfrac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^m}=e^{\log\bigg(\dfrac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^m}\bigg)}=e^{\log(e^{-1/x^2})-\log(x^m)}=e^{-1/x^2-m\log(x)}\to e^{-\infty}\to 0.$$
Note that $-1/x^2-m\log(x)=-\dfrac{1+mx^2\log x}{x^2}$, where $mx^2\log x= \dfrac{m\log x}{\dfrac{1}{x^2}} \longrightarrow _{D.H.}0$, so $-\dfrac{1+mx^2\log x}{x^2}\longrightarrow_{x \to 0} -1/x^2 \longrightarrow_{x \to 0}-\infty$.

Comment: How did you get $-1/x^2-m\log(x)\sim_{x\to 0}-1/x^2$? @psidaga I thought as x→0, log(x) would be -$\infty$

Comment: I wrote some details in my answer... Let me know if it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

With $t:=\dfrac1{x^2}$ we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^m}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t^{m/2}}{e^{t}},$$ which is easily tractable by L'Hospital (or just knowing that the exponential grows faster).

Answer (score 0):

$\ln(e^{-1/x^2}/x^m)
=\ln(e^{-1/x^2})-\ln(x^m)
=-\frac 1{x^2}-m\ln(x)
=\underbrace{-\frac 1{x^2}}_{\to-\infty}\bigg(1+ \underbrace{mx^2\ln(x)}_{\to 0}\bigg)\to-\infty$

Indeed you can use this result: $\ \lim\limits_{u\to 0}\ u\ln(u)=0\ $ there are plenty of proofs on this site.

Therefore $\quad mx^2\ln(x)=\frac m2x^2\ln(x^2)\to 0$ applied for $u=x^2$

And you can conclude that $f(x)=o(x^m)$ for all $m$.